# How to add Portable Document Format (PDF) content type to Application of Firefox browser opened by WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In a web page I am working there is an icon, On clicking this icon one pop up will open and in this pop up PDF will be shown. PDF is shown inside iframe. My problem is whenever I run my script and webdriver opens the firefox browser. On clicking the icon PDF is actually auto downloading instead of showing in pop up. Below is the Browser Preference code. I am using.

```
FirefoxProfile fprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\AutomationFramework\\ResultFiles");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/x-excel, application/x-msexcel, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/xls, text/csv, application/pdf, multipart/x-zip,application/zip,application/x-zip-compressed,application/x-compressed,image/jpeg,image/png,image/svg+xml");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/xls, multipart/x-zip,application/zip,application/x-zip-compressed,application/x-compressed,image/jpeg,image/png,image/svg+xml");
fprofile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
fprofile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", false );
fprofile.setPreference("plugin.scan.plid.all",false);
fprofile.setPreference("plugin.scan.Acrobat","99.0");       
fprofile.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types","application/pdf;application/x-excel, application/x-msexcel, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel,application/xls, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Below is applications screen shot of Firefox Browser opened by WebDriver. What should I add in Preference code so that instead of PDF auto download it should display in pop up inside iframe.
I am using Firefox version 46.

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Selenium Webdriver by default is not using any firefox profile in firefox.exe -p. That means if the screen is from any of those existing profiles, it is irelevant.

Seems to missing the right mime type for PDF, but I use to access an existing firefox profile, see [Automatically download pdf in firefox gecko driver using selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276253/automatically-download-pdf-in-firefox-gecko-driver-using-selenium-java)

You just need to create firefox profile manualy, modify handling PDF file also manualy and in code access the modified profile.